# Best sampling method within the normal family

Tags: bayesian, inference, bias-variance-tradeoff

Suppose that we want to make the best Bayesian inference about some value $\mu$ we have some normal prior about it. I.e. $\mu\sim N(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2)$ with known parameters. To do so, we can choose parameters $(\mu_x, \sigma_x)$ that define a normal sampling method with mean $\mu_s=\mu \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_0^2}+\mu_x\frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_0^2}$ and variance $\sigma_s^2=\frac{\sigma_0^2\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_0^2+\sigma_x^2}$.

Can it be shown that the optimal value of $\mu_x$ is $\mu_x=\mu_0$?

Can it be shown that the optimal value of $\sigma_x$ is an intermediate value, i.e. $\sigma_x\in(0,\infty)$?

Can the optimal value of $\sigma_x$ be characterized in closed form?

Details: to be more precise, after choosing parameters $(\mu_x,\sigma_x)$ we will get an observation from the induced normal distribution and the goal is for the expected posterior to be as close as possible to $\mu$

Comment: Could you please explain what a "normal sampling method" is and tell us what you assume about the distribution you are sampling from?  You have explained your prior but you haven't said anything at all about the actual model!  BTW, is the SD of the prior intended to equal its mean, or is that a typographical error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, the SD of my prior is not necessarily equal to the mean, that was a typo. It has been fixed, thanks for pointing it out. What I mean by the sampling method is that you will see a realization of a random variable that is distributed $N(\mu_s, \sigma_s^2)$. I am an economist, so I am sorry if I am not familiar with the way models are typically introduced here.

Comment: So as an economist, I think of an agent that after observing the realization of the random variable has to choose a number and the goal is to choose a number that in expectation (according to the prior) is closest to the true (unknown) value $\mu$. The second part of choosing the best number is easy since you choose the the mean of your posterior belief after observing a realization. My question is about choosing the best pair of $(\mu_x, \sigma^2_x)$ that define $(\mu_s, \sigma_s^2)$.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a free lunch. After prior, you do not collect any more information related to $\mu$, then you want "the expected posterior to be as close as possible to μ". It is impossible. Simulation cannot be used for this kind of purpose.

Comment: @user158565 I'm not sure I follow. after the prior you will observe a realization from the random variable that distributes normal with mean $\mu_s$ and variance $\sigma^2_s$. This observation is (in general) informative about $\mu$.

Comment: Your so called 'observation' comes from simulation.